# Position of nodes and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

I am trying to reproduce this slide. I have written some code to produce some thing similar but the positions of nodes and type of arrows are hard to get. This is what I am aiming for

[image: Slide showing desired arrows]

and this is what I have

[image: Current slide]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}%  For \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{calc}%    For the \widthof macro
\newcommand{\Text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. }
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Line and Marker Options}
\begin{itemize}
\item Everything on a line can be customized
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,]

%\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3);

\coordinate  (origin) at (0,0);

%\node at (origin) {*};

\coordinate  (text1) at (3.5,3);


\node  [text width=8.0cm,]at (text1) {\scriptsize{\fontseries{b}\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{ 
{>>  plot(x,y,\lq --s', \lq LineWidth',2,\dots\\
\mytikzmark{block1a}{\lq}\mytikzmark{block1b}{C}olor',[1 0 0],\dots\\
\mytikzmark{block2a}{\lq Marker} \mytikzmark{block2b}{Edge}Color',\lq k',\dots\\
\lq MarkerFaceColor',\lq g',\dots \\
\lq MarkerSize',10)
}}}}};

\node [text width=4.5cm, anchor=west] at (-4, 1) (blocka1) {You can set colors by using a vector [RGB] values or a predefined color character like \lq g',\lq k',etc.};

\draw[black,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (blocka1) -- ($(block1a)!0.5!(block1b)$);
\draw[black,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (blocka1) -- ($(block2a)!0.5!(block2b)$);
\node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (5,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{fig4.png}};

\draw[<-,thick] (russell.north) -- (text1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{itemize}
\item See \textcolor{orange}{doc line\_props} for a full list of properties that can be specified. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\subnode` from `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}%  For \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{calc}%    For the \widthof macro
\newcommand{\Text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. }
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Line and Marker Options}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Everything on a line can be customized
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{figure}[h]
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,]
        \coordinate  (origin) at (0,0);
        \coordinate  (text1) at (3.5,3);
        \node  [text width=8.0cm,]at (text1) {%
          \scriptsize{%
            \bfseries\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{%
                {>>  plot(x,y,\lq --s', \lq LineWidth',2,\dots\\
                  \subnode{block1a}{\lq {C}olor',[1 0 0],\dots}
                  \subnode{block2a}{\lq Marker {Edge}Color',\lq k',\dots}
                  \lq MarkerFaceColor',\lq g',\dots\\
                  \lq MarkerSize',10)
                }}}}};
        \node [text width=4.5cm, anchor=west] at (-4, 1) (blocka1) {You can set colors by using a vector [RGB] values or a predefined color character like \lq g',\lq k',etc.};
        \draw[black,-stealth, thick, ] (blocka1.north) -- ([yshift=-.5em]block1a.west);
        \draw[black,-stealth, thick, ] (blocka1.north) -- ([yshift=-.5em]block2a.west);
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (5,0) {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
        \draw [{Triangle[open, length=5mm, width=10mm]}-{Butt Cap[]}, thick, double distance=4mm, rounded corners=5mm, postaction={draw, {}-{}, white, line width=4mm, shorten <=4mm, shorten >=.8pt}] (russell.north) |- (text1.south east);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item See \textcolor{orange}{doc line\_props} for a full list of properties that can be specified.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: subnodes]

Comment: The arrows on the left should be pointing to the words: 'color' and marker. How can I ket the tip points towards them?

Comment: @MAS See edit...

Comment: I was searching for some documentation on subnode but with no luck. Can you please point me to one? @cfr

Comment: @MAS `texdoc tikzmark`.

Comment: @MAS I know the question was about positioning, but I wanted to improve the large arrow so I've edited my answer accordingly.